# Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']

Tags: python, google-app-engine, header, rss, web-scraping

I try to run simple scrap script to generate rss on gae. but getting this error. I searched all stackoverflow answer but it didnt help

```
urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']
```

I use this script

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
import sys
sys.path.append('libs/')
reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch


from datetime import datetime
import locale

import PyRSS2Gen
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
import requests
import codecs

class yenitem:
        baslik= ""
        link=""
        aciklama=""
        zaman=datetime.now()

def parse(url):
     page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
     soup=BeautifulSoup(page.read())

##     request=urllib.Request(url)
##     request.add_header('Accept-Encoding','utf-8')
##     response=urllib2.urlopen(request)
##     response=urlfetch.fetch( url, headers={ "User-Agent" : user_agent } ).content


##     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))

     items=[]
##     print soup

     for link in soup.find_all('article',{'class':'item-list'}):

         item=yenitem()

         item.baslik=link.find_all('h2')[0].get_text()
         item.link= link.find_all('a')[0].get('href')
         item.aciklama= link.find_all('div')[1].get_text()

         item.zaman=link.find_all('span')[0].get_text()





         items.append(item)
     return items
```

error log :

```
2015-01-28 00:10:23 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Users\\bigM\\Desktop\\gomhg\\denemer']"
INFO     2015-01-28 00:10:28,510 devappserver2.py:745] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-01-28 00:10:28,585 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:61808
INFO     2015-01-28 00:10:28,589 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-01-28 00:10:28,592 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
WARNING  2015-01-28 00:10:32,867 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0"><channel><title>ff</title><link></link><description></description><lastBuildDate></lastBuildDate><generator>PyRSS2Gen-1.0.0</generator><docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs><item><title>Destan yazanlar, yazd&#305;ranlar</title><link>http://www.taraf.com.tr/yazarlar/destan-yazanlar-yazdiranlar/</link><description>
.....
```

Comment: Besides many dubious uses, you're **not** using `urlfetch` at all (it's commented out!) and there's a mysterious `page` with an equally mysterious `urllib2` attribute appearing out of nowhere.  Please show us some actual code *AND* the exact traceback you observed from the actual code, not these modified excerpts with an error in isolation and no way at all to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: @AlexMartelli editted the ques. I thought it was about beautifulsoup or urllib2

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning.  You're running the simulation of `urllib2` (without even importing `urllib2`, which guarantees the code you're showing is **not** what you're running -- you're showing code importing `urllib` and `urlfetch` then not using either but using the never-imported `urllib2`!) that GAE builds on top of its `urlfetch` and the `host` header (which you're not explicitly passing) isn't supported -- no big deal.  Just use `urlfetch` directly and simplify your life, if you want to

Comment: @AlexMartell I guess my codes are messed up because I tried different combinations:) It gives the same warning if I change urllib to urllib2. I try to  generate http://localhost:8080/rss.xml page but It's not working. Is there any chance you can check this project ? it just has 2 files https://yadi.sk/d/EBbft-8NeHPuW  when I change in app.yaml script: controllers/runk.py to script: controllers/rss.py it generates this page. I couldnt find where the problem is

Comment: my problem was after I wrote this sys.path.append('libs/') I was trying to import a module which in same directory and having that same module in libs folder. I was trying to change the module in same directory not in libs folder :(

Comment: The code as it stands just has too many commented-out parths, obvious breakages, and terrible practices.  `rss.py` is nice and clean -- `from libs import PyRSS2Gen` and everything; `runk.py` is a mess -- appends `libs` to sys.path in order to import stuff from there (why not just `from libs import` just like in nice clean rss.py?!), forces default encoding (never do that!), &c.  And of course I don't understand its terms -- it's your choice to use whatever language you prefer but that too makes it MUCH harder to help you for those who don't speak that language.

Comment: And incidentally the subject of this Q is **not** your problem and has nothing much to do with the messes in runk and what it imports.